# I want to clarify one step in Schwarz' (Clairaut’s) theorem proof.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

When we get equation $$f''_{xy}(x_0+\theta_0h_0,y_0+\theta_1h_1)=f''_{yx}(x_0+\theta_2h_0,y_0+\theta_3h_1),$$ where $$0<\theta_0,\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3<1$$ from Lagrange's theorem (mean value theorem). 
Then go to limit as $$(h_0,h_1)\to 0$$
From continuity of $$f''_{xy}~,~~~~ f''_{yx}$$ we get $$f^{\prime\prime}_{xy}(x_0+\theta_0h_0,y_0+\theta_1h_1)\to f''_{xy}(x_0,y_0)$$$$f''_{yx}(x_0+\theta_2h_0,y_0+\theta_3h_1)\to f''_{yx}(x_0,y_0)$$
We can say that $$f''_{xy}(x_0,y_0) = f''_{yx}(x_0,y_0)$$ 
from everything I mentioned or there is something else I didn`t notice? Why we can say that these limits are equal?